# Расширение для браузера: как задать соответствующие стили для сотен различных URL?

Tags: javascript, расширения

Изучаю создание расширений для браузеров. Самый простой [пример на сайте Мозиллы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) создаёт красную рамочку в окне браузера при условии совпадения URL сайта с заданным вручную в расширении в файле `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Adds a solid red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "borderify@mozilla.org",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Решил изменить этот плагин так, чтобы для заданных URL было своё отображение рамочки, например, для сайта Мозиллы и Гугла - красная, а для сайтов браузера Опера и портала Stackoverflow - зеленая рамочка.

Методом проб и ошибок сделал это, изменив файл манифеста следующим образом:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*", "*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.opera.com/*", "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify_green.js"]
    }
  ]
```

и добавив файл `borderify_green.js` с новыми стилями для зелёной рамки.

Всё работает, но если мне вдруг понадобится делать подобное для десятков-сотен сайтов? Тогда надо как-то выносить все эти URL'ы и ссылки на скрипты, к ним относящиеся, в отдельный файл, правильно?

Как это правильно сделать?

За прошедшее время я изучал другие расширения для браузеров, документацию и спрашивал знакомых знакомых, кто более менее сносно владеет `javascript`'ом. В итоге процентов на 80 добился того, что хотел, поэтому пока что сам на этот вопрос не отвечаю, а дополняю старт-пост.

Значит, в файле `manifest.json` следует оставить следующее, относящееся к свойству `content_scripts`:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Вся логика теперь переносится в скрипт `borderify.js`:

```
const controllers={
    'javascript.ru':()=>{
    document.body.style.border='solid 5px red';
    },
    'www.google.com':()=>{
    document.body.style.border='solid 5px green';
    },
    'stackoverflow.com':()=>{
        document.body.style.border='solid 5px blue';
    }
};

if(!!controllers[location.hostname])
    controllers[location.hostname]();
```

Осталось разобраться с поддоменами, поскольку выражения типа `*.stackoverflow.com` со свойствами `host` и `hostname` не работают, поэтому для домена гугла пришлось явно указывать `www`: `www.google.com`.

Если кто может помочь с проблемой выделения домена без поддоменов в этом скрипте, буду признателен.

Comment: Вы можете прямо в `borderify.js` определить, какой `url` страницы и соответственно этому строить логику.

Comment: А что тогда в 'matches' оставить? '*://*/*'?

Comment: Я не силен в расширениях, но возможно `matches` можно вообще не указывать.